# Oracle database installation issue in ins_ctx.mk

Tags: oracle11g

```
Error in invoking target 'install' of makefile '/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/ctx/lib/ins_ctx.mk'. See '/u01/app/oraInventory/logs/installActions2015-02-28_02-22-27AM.log' for details.
```

I get the above error when I run  the installer of Oracle 11g release 2

The log is as follows

```
INFO: gcc -o ctxhx -m64 -L/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/ctx/lib/ -L/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/lib/ -L/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/lib/stubs/  /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/ctx/lib/ctxhx.o -L/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/ctx/lib/ -lm -ldl -lsc_ca -lsc_fa -lsc_ex -lsc_da -lsc_ut -lsc_ch -lsc_fi -lctxhx -lc -Wl,-rpath,/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/ctx/lib -lsnls11 -lnls11  -lcore11 -lsnls11 -lnls11 -lcore11 -lsnls11 -lnls11 -lxml11 -lcore11 -lunls11 -ls
INFO: nls11 -lnls11 -lcore11 -lnls11

INFO: /usr/bin/ld: /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/lib//libcore11.a(sslss.o): undefined reference to symbol 'pthread_sigmask@@GLIBC_2.2.5'
//lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line

INFO: collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

INFO: make: *** [ctxhx] Error 1

INFO: End output from spawned process.
INFO: ----------------------------------
INFO: Exception thrown from action: make
Exception Name: MakefileException
Exception String: Error in invoking target 'install' of makefile '/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/ctx/lib/ins_ctx.mk'. See '/u01/app/oraInventory/logs/installActions2015-02-28_02-22-27AM.log' for details.
```

Please help me fix this... Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Try to link with g++ instead of gcc.

```
cd /bin
mv gcc gcc.save
ln -s g++ gcc
```

and run the installer again.

Comment: what is the consequences if I ignored this error message and I clicked continued instead ?

Comment: In my case, I had no option.  It failed all further steps.

Answer (score 0):

Create the following script the run it a root during install the click retry

```
# Fix ctx/lib/ins_ctx.mk

ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/db_1

cat << __EOF__ > /tmp/memcpy_wrap.c
#include <stddef.h>
#include <string.h>

asm (".symver wrap_memcpy, memcpy@GLIBC_2.14");
void *wrap_memcpy(void *dest, const void *src, size_t n) {
return memcpy(dest, src, n);
}
__EOF__

if [[ -e "${ORACLE_HOME}/ctx/lib/ins_ctx.mk" ]]; then
sed -i -e 's/\$(INSO_LINK)/\$(INSO_LINK) -Wl,--wrap=memcpy_wrap \$(ORACLE_HOME)\/ctx\/lib\/memcpy_wrap.o/g' ${ORACLE_HOME}/ctx/lib/ins_ctx.mk
gcc -c /tmp/memcpy_wrap.c -o ${ORACLE_HOME}/ctx/lib/memcpy_wrap.o && rm /tmp/memcpy_wrap.c
fi
```